# Validation Rules when Clicking in a New Object

Tags: apex, validation-rule

I would like to create a validation rule that does not allow me to create a new object inside of a lead unless I have certain fields fulfilled.

[image]

Could you please help me with code?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide any code you've attempted? It will also be helpful to understand how your objects are setup. Are these fields you want fulfilled on the lead or the custom object? At the moment, it looks like you would be able to achieve this through the configurable validation rules which would be the easiest approach.

Comment: why don't you put the direct validation rules? why coding again?

Comment: I don't have any code. I don't know how to do it. These fields must be fulfilled on the lead. I don't want to put it in the object validation rules because people will have to go back and fulfil the fields they forgot. If they click on the button and the error appears it would be better.

Could you please help? What do you need from me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `Prospective Property` is a child to `Lead`. Then, to prevent a new `Propsective Property` from being saved when the parent Lead isn't ready:

**Validation Rule**

```
OR(Lead__r.someFld <> 'someVal',
   Lead__r.someOtherFld <> = 'someOtherVal',
   NOT(ISPICKVAL(Lead__r.somePicklist,'somepicklistVal'))
)
```

If the user gets a Save error, they merely need open the `Lead` from the recent items sidebar in another browser tab and complete the missing fields, then go back and click SAVE on the new `Prospective Property` edit page. Your VR error message can tell them to do this.